# why the function cleanup_str must be qualified with 'static' key word?

Tags: c++, static, constants

I am new programmer of c++. I have encountered a proble and I cannot understand this. Could you please help me figure out it? This is an example of the book,<c++ primer>.

```
class TextQuery {
public:
    using line_no = std::vector<std::string>::size_type;
    TextQuery(std::ifstream &);
    QueryResult query(const std::string &)  const;
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> file;
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<std::set<line_no>>> wm;
    //static std::string cleanup_str(const std::string &); // the book example uses 'static'
    std::string cleanup_str(const std::string &); // I think 'static' key word is not needed.so i remove it.
};//class declearation ends here.

std::string TextQuery::cleanup_str(const std::string &word)  {
    string ret;
    for(auto it = word.begin();it != word.end();++it){
        if(!ispunct(*it))
            ret += tolower(*it);
    }
    return ret;
}

QueryResult TextQuery::query(const std::string &sought) const 
{
    static shared_ptr<set<line_no>> nodata(new set<line_no>);    //line 66
    auto loc = wm.find(cleanup_str(sought));                     //line 67

    if(loc == wm.end())
        return QueryResult(sought,nodata,file);
    else
    {
        return QueryResult(sought,loc->second,file);
    }  
}
```

I cannot unstandard the difference between the version of removing 'static' key word and that does not. The compile error is:

```
passing 'const TextQuery' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive],67
the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "TextQuery::cleanup_str" -- object type is: const TextQuery,67
```

I have tried two ways that can work correctly:

1. add `'static'` to the function `cleanup_str`. I cannot unstand why it can pass.
2. The other way I tried is: remove the last `'const'` key word of function `QueryResult TextQuery::query(const std::string &sought) const`, make it become: `QueryResult TextQuery::query(const std::string &sought)` . And this method works, I also cannot understand this reason.

Comment: Since `cleanup_str` doesn't do anything to any instance of the `TextQuery` class, there doesn't seem to be any reason for it to be a non-static class member function. Is there some reason for that decision?

Comment: What the compiler tells you is that `query` is a `const` member function, and cannot call non-const member functions. So either make `cleanup_str` also `const`, or in this case better make it `static` since it has no good reason to be non-static.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  This is an example from a textbook. For me, I orginally think that there is no need to make this function to be a static member function. So i remove it and fail to compile this program. There is no other reasons.

Comment: @zenos The reason to make it a static member function is that it can be static. If there's no reason to make it non-static, then it should be static. Why require an object and require a non-const object when there is no reason for that requirement?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You mean ,all function members can be static?right? I cannot understand you question---"Why require an object and require a non-const object when there is no reason for that requirement?" . Can you give me an example?

Comment: An example is right there in your code. `cleanup_str` doesn't make reference to any of the member variables of the `TextQuery` class. It doesn't care about the `file` or `wm` variables, it just takes a `std::string` as input, processes it, and returns a `stdf::string` as output. So why should it be forced to depend on some specific `TextQuery` object when it doesn't have to?

Comment: @NathanPierson Understand. Yes, I also think `cleanup_str` could be independent of any objects. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` method has a contract - it does not change internal state of an instance of the class. Technically it is implemented the way that hidden parameter `this` has type `const TextQuery *` - pointer to constant (non modifiable) object of `TextQuery`. To follow that contract you cannot call **non constant** method, it may modify internal state and brake contract of original, const method. Now -

> add 'static' to the function cleanup_str. I cannot unstand why it can pass.

Static method does not work with an instance, it just belongs to that class (it does not have hidden parameter `this` at all) hence it is safe to call such method from `const` method, contract would not be broken. If you remove `static` then that method becomes regular **non const** method and it is not safe to call it anymore from `const` one.

> The other way I tried is: remove the last 'const' key word of function QueryResult

Now your method `query` becomes non constant (type of `this` is `TextQuery *`) so it is safe to call non constant or static method from it. So your compiler error disappear.